# Trying to create a powershell script to install a program on a remote computer on the same network

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, elevated-privileges

I'm very new to Powershell and I am trying to create a script whereby I copy a folder from one computer to another computer on the same network, and then run a batch file as an admin on the remote computer when a regular user is logged in.

Here is what I have so, issue is, I can't get Powershell to run the batch file with admin rights.

The reason I want to run the batch file is the exe in the batch file needs parameters to run, and Powershell doesn't recognize them.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "computer Name" -Credential "Admin creds"
Copy-Item -Path "\Local computer folder\*" -Destination "\\computer Name\C$\Temp" -Recurse -Force
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computer" -Credential "Admin creds" -ScriptBlock {  
  Start-Process c:\temp\Install.bat -wait  
}
Remove-Item –path \\computer Name\C$\Temp –recurse
Remove-PSSession $session
```

I have tried several different commands, with no luck.

Comment: How is this failing, and with what error messages?

Comment: `c:\temp\Install.bat arg1 arg2`  You probably don't need start-process.

Comment: All works fine, and I don't get any error messages in powershell, it's just that the program won't install, thinking it's because it doesn't have elevated creds . I can run Powershell with elevated creds on the remote machine, it's a test PC in my office, and use the same commands, and it works fine.

Comment: If the calling user is an administrator, the remote command _invariably_ runs with elevation (with admin privileges), so that is likely not the problem. The remote command will run with the caller's user identity, and independently of whether a user is logged on or not. In other words: you cannot use this approach to perform an installation _for a different user_. It's not clear what you mean by _PowerShell doesn't recognize them_.

Comment: c:\temp\Install.bat arg1 arg2 is not working. Parameters I need to run are -s -f1c:\temp\script.iss

Comment: What you can do is create a scheduled task to run under the specified user with administrator credentials that you give it

Comment: I think I figured it out
Replaced {  Start-Process c:\temp\Install.bat -wait  }
With {  & c:\temp\Install.bat -wait  }

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**, based on your own feedback:

Replacing `{ Start-Process c:\temp\Install.bat -wait }` as the `-ScriptBlock` argument with:

```
{ c:\temp\Install.bat -wait }
```

fixes your problem; it ensures:

- *synchronous* (blocking) execution of the batch file...

  - As an aside: While you're always free to use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) in direct invocation (`& c:\temp\Install.bat -wait`), it is only *required* if the executable path is *quoted* (usually due to containing *spaces*) and/or is expressed in terms of *variables*.
- ... with `-wait` being passed as an argument *to `c:\temp\Install.bat`*.

---

###### Background information:

Your problem boiled down to this:

> `Start-Process c:\temp\Install.bat -wait`

You expected `-wait` to be a *pass-through* argument, i.e. to be passed to `c:\temp\Install.bat`

However, `-wait` was interpreted by [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) as *its* `-Wait` switch, so that it *synchronously* ran your batch file, *but without passing it any arguments*.

The *immediate* fix would have been:

- ***Quote* your pass-through argument(s), which is a must *if it looks like a parameter name***.
- ***Also* pass *`Start-Process`*' `-Wait` switch**, which is a must in a remote call with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) that creates an *ad hoc* remote session due to using the `-ComputerName` parameter:

  - The session is closed when `Invoke-Command` returns, and if a remotely and asynchronously `Start-Process`-launched process hasn't completed yet at that point, it will be *killed*.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computer Name" -Credential "Admin creds" -ScriptBlock {  
  # Note the use of -Wait for Start-Process and '-wait' as the pass-through argument.
  Start-Process -Wait c:\temp\Install.bat '-wait' 
}
```

However, except in special cases **there's *no* good reason to use `Start-Process` to *synchronously* invoke *console* applications** (such as batch files), so the ***direct invocation*** solution at the top is **preferable**:

- Direct invocation, in addition to being *invariably synchronous* with console applications, also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).
- [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

---

As for your **concern about running with *elevation* (administrative privileges)**:

- **If the calling user is an administrator, the remote command *invariably* runs with elevation**, and by default it is only administrators that are permitted to perform [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) operations.
- The remote command will run with the *caller's* user identity (which by default is the user identity of the calling session, but can be overridden with the `-Credential` parameter), which is unrelated to whether or which user happens to be logged on at the target machine.

  - In other words: you cannot use a remoting call to perform an installation *for a different user*.